# Storing a pair of numbers each time in a one-dimensional array in C

Tags: c, arrays

I'm a beginner in C. I am having trouble with this array function. When I call the function, it will ask for the input of a pair of numbers (key, value) each time, and store it in a one-dimensional array. I will have to store the pair one-by-one by constantly calling the function. Below is what I have currently and I think I'm not storing it correctly

edit: sorry, noticed how bad my question was. I think I'm not storing it correctly as when I call upon other functions such as sum (summing the values), I get 0 or the wrong answer. Also, updated the code to include main function for further details. The size of the array is limited to 100.

```
#define SIZE 100
int main(void) {
int arr[SIZE] = {0};

void insert_table(int arr[], int length) {
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<SIZE; i=i+2){
        scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
        scanf("%d", &arr[i+1];
        break;
    }
```

Comment: You think you're not doing it correctly? Why? What are your concerns? Does your code work? If not, how? Also provide a [mcve]

Comment: Perhaps you need to do some [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) of your function?

Comment: Why don't you use `length`?

Comment: `int;` looks like a typo for `int i;`. Although you can put that into the `for` loop: `for (int i = 0; i < length; i+=2)`

Comment: The current code wont even compile at all. and it is far from complete.

Comment: Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly learn how to create a [mcve].

Comment: Please upload your valid code instead of trying to take a shortcut.

Answer (score 1):

In

> ```
> void insert_table(int arr[], int length) {
>     int i;
>     for (i=0; i<SIZE; i=i+2){
>         scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
>         scanf("%d", &arr[i+1];
>         break;
>     }
> ```

you have several problems :

- the *break* stop your loop after you (try to) enter two values, this is probably not what you wanted to do
- you do not check the result of *scanf*, so you do not detect EOF nor invalid input
- you suppose *SIZE* is even, if odd you will write out of *arr* with an undefined behavior

Probably also *length* is the number of entries in *arr* to not have to use *SIZE* in `insert_table`

To return the number of entries set will help the caller in case of EOF/error if all the entries are not set

A better definition is :

```
size_t insert_table(int arr[], size_t length) {
  size_t i;

  for (i = 0; i < length - 1; i += 2){
    if ((scanf("%d", &arr[i]) != 1) ||
        (scanf("%d", &arr[i+1]) != 1))
      return i;
  }

  return i;
}
```

If I add that main :

```
#define SIZE 100

int main()
{
  int arr[SIZE];
  size_t n = insert_table(arr, SIZE);

  for (size_t i = 0; i != n; i += 2) {
    printf("%d %d\n", arr[i], arr[i + 1]);
  }
}
```

Compilation and execution :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc -pedantic -Wextra s.c
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
1 2 3 4 a
1 2
3 4
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ echo "1 2 3 4" | ./a.out
1 2
3 4
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ echo "1 2 3 4 5" | ./a.out
1 2
3 4
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```